# Deprecation warning when using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, momentjs

I am using moment.js and moment-timezone.js for date time calculations in my code.
After a while (so this wasn't a problem in a first place) I have started getting warning message saying this:

> vendor.js:50531 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a
>   recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(),
>   which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:  [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false,
>   _l: undefined, _i: , _f: , _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object] Error
>       at Function.createFromInputFallback (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:50558:98)
>       at configFromString (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52297:32)
>       at configFromInput (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52657:13)
>       at prepareConfig (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52640:13)
>       at createFromConfig (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52607:44)
>       at createLocalOrUTC (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52694:16)
>       at local__createLocal (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:52698:16)
>       at utils_hooks__hooks (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:50265:29)
>       at new CalenderCtrl (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:111047:18)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8001/public/js/vendor.js:17317:19)

I have no clue what this means, even after searching thorough moment.js docs.

This is a part of code where I use moment.js:

```
convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients() {
        let timeZoneInfo = {
            usersTimeZone: this.$rootScope.mtz.tz.guess(),
            utcOffset: this.formData.timeZone.offset,
            selectedDateTime: this.toJSONLocal(this.formData.sessionDate) + " " + this.formData.sessionTime 
        };

        let utcTime  = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(timeZoneInfo.selectedDateTime).utcOffset(timeZoneInfo.utcOffset).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        let formatedUtcTime = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(utcTime).toDate();
        let localTime = this.$rootScope.mtz(formatedUtcTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        this.$scope.clientDateTimeZone = localTime;
}
```

Does somebody sees some potential problem that can cause this warning.
The only thing I can think of is that 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm' is not ISO format, but I need to use this format anyhow.

Comment: A related issue on github https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3440

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` is included in the _Supported ISO 8601 strings_ listed in the official [parsing docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), which is the line and the string value that gives you _Deprecation warning_?

Comment: how to get know where is the line for the warning ? i got some issue but there is not throw where the line of code , oh my ...

Answer (score 0):

`this.$rootScope.mtz(formatedUtcTime)` -

you may need to pass in the format that you find the time in currently. 
i.e.

`this.$rootScope.mtz(formatedUtcTime, "MM-DD-YYYY")`

to help the parser understand the format. I'd guess the internal parser is choking on whatever format that date is in currently.